# where to find server certificate in a TLS1.3 handshake capture

Tags: certificate, handshake, tls1.3

I captured with wireshark a TLSv1.3 handshake established between a client and server that both support TLSv1.3. I know that the certificate is being sent in an encrypted form but i can't find any field that indicate that here we find the encrypted certificate. Any help please?

Answer (score 5):

In TLS 1.3 servers send their certificates **encrypted**.

In TLS 1.3 client and server exchange keys at the very beginning: client sends its choice in ClientHello, and the server sends its `key_share` in ServerHello. Everything after ServerHello is encrypted.

It differs drastically from SSL/TLS prior to TLS 1.3, where key exchange happened AFTER authentication. In SSL and TLS 1-1.2 certificates were sent as plain text.

If you open [RFC 8446 on Page 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-2), you will see the message exchange diagram. Please find the server-side `{Certificate*}` message. The notation `{*}` means:

- asterisk (*) indicates this is an optional message,
- braces `{}` indicate that

> messages protected using keys derived from a [sender]_handshake_traffic_secret

More formally [RFC 8446 section 4.4 specifies](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-4.4):

> As discussed in Section 2, TLS generally uses a common set of
> messages for authentication, key confirmation, and handshake
> integrity: Certificate, CertificateVerify, and Finished.  ...
> These messages are encrypted under keys derived from the
> [sender]_handshake_traffic_secret.